# How to setup multisuit tagging for mobile app in adobe mobile service

Tags: mobile-application, adobe-analytics

I want to setup multisuit tagging for my mobile app but i am not able to understand what steps should follow to do multisuit tagging in Adobe Mobile Service.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not a way to specify multiple report suites within the Adobe Mobile Services interface. However, you can edit the `ADBMobileConfig.json` file to include multiple report suite ids in a comma delimited list (no spaces).

```
{
  // ,...
  "analytics": {
    "rsids": "rsid1,rsid2"
    // ,...
  }
  // ,...
}
```

Just remember if you make other config changes in the interface and re-download the config file, you will need to remember to update that value.